# SQL Server : select integer from string into new table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to extract 6-7 digit document IDs from variously formatted strings (urls)
I would prefer this done as a database query.

Background:

Basically I need to build a new url based on the docid identified in the existing url, these are in a EXTERNAL_REF database column

For example:

```
http://*******/root/wrks/stores/default/default/pdf/docid/999762/dw_get
```

will become

```
https://******/Prod/Anywhere/Web/Prod/ShowFunction/page?sk.DocumentId=999762&suite=ADT
```

Example source data:

```
default/default/orig/docid/999980/pageno/1/dw_get
default/default/orig/docid/999986/pageno/1/dw_get
default/yyy/orig/docid/1000001/pageno/67/dw_get
78/default/orig/docid=1000480/pageno/1/dw_get
default/default/orig/docid=1000516/pageno/767/dw_get
default/default/orig/docid=1000527/pageno/1/dw_get
default/xxx/pdf/docid=999762/dw_get
default/default/orig/docid/1000581/pageno/1/dw_get
679/default/pdf/docid/999761/dw_get
default/default/orig/docid/1000590/pageno/1/dw_get
default/default/orig/docid/985747/dw_get
```

Required result:

```
999980
999986
1000001
1000480
1000516
1000527
999762
1000581
999761
1000590
985747
```

Comment: Your source data shows two different instances: `docid/999980` and `docid=1000516`. Is this correct?  Or will every line of your source data follow the exact same structure?

Comment: you are correct, there are different formats throughout the records.

The two patterns that should match most if not all would be:

=1015724& where the number could be 6 or 7 digits or 

/1015574/ where the number could be 6 or 7 digits

Comment: What have i tried?
 Quite a lot but nothing that is getting me close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      string NVARCHAR(150)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (string)
VALUES 
    ('default/default/orig/docid/999980/pageno/1/dw_get'),
('default/default/orig/docid/999986/pageno/1/dw_get'),
('default/yyy/orig/docid/1000001/pageno/67/dw_get'),
('78/default/orig/docid=1000480/pageno/1/dw_get'),
('default/default/orig/docid=1000516/pageno/767/dw_get'),
('default/default/orig/docid=1000527/pageno/1/dw_get'),
('default/xxx/pdf/docid=999762/dw_get'),
('default/default/orig/docid/1000581/pageno/1/dw_get'),
('679/default/pdf/docid/999761/dw_get'),
('default/default/orig/docid/1000590/pageno/1/dw_get'),
('default/default/orig/docid/985747/dw_get')

-- get the data after docid in the string
;with report as(
select substring(string,CHARINDEX('docid',string,0)+6,len(string)) as string
from @temp
)
-- get the the number up to next '/'
select substring(string,0,charindex('/',string,0))
from report
```

for using one query, you can combine both scripts in same query as

```
select substring(substring(string,charindex('docid',string,0)+6,len(string)),0,
                 charindex('/',substring(string,
                 charindex('docid',string,0)+6,len(string)),0))
from @temp
```

Here a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c3d683/1)

Hope this will help you

Comment: This is close

`select substring(EXTERNAL_REF,CHARINDEX('docid',EXTERNAL_REF,0)+6,len(EXTERNAL_REF)) as result
from table`

the above strips everything before the number. leaving

`1000581/pageno/1/dw_get
999761/dw_get
1000590/pageno/1/dw_get
985747/dw_get
998909/dw_get
985954/dw_get
987691/dw_get
1001524&page=1&filename=pdf
1001723/pageno/1/dw_get
1001746/pageno/1/dw_get
1002235&page=1&filename=pdf`

i couldn't get the one query solution to return anything.

Comment: kindly have a look on the demo i created, i edited the answer, the solution i provided was detailed and combined, the demo contains the combined solution. The whole idea is to extract the digits right after `docid/ or docid=` till the next `/` . so the idea was to find the index of docid in the string then add 6 to reach after = or / then ( index of '/' - index of (docid +6 )) and you will get the number as shown in the demo.

Comment: it is clear you tried the cte solution which is two steps solution, you need then to apply the triming till first '/' (in the cte solution). but i recommend you use the second combined query. Hope this will help you

Comment: Hi Monah,
your solution is so close Thank you. Based on my question you nailed it. The problem i have now is that the character after the number can be a / or a & can your sql be modified to allow for this? I can move forward with what i have but a one script solution would be super nice.

Answer (score 0):

String manipulations are clumsy in SQL Server, but you can do:

```
select v2.*
from t cross apply
     (values (stuff(url, 1, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', t.url) - 1, '') )
     ) v1(url1) cross apply
     (values (left(v1.url1, charindex('/', v1.url1) - 1))
     ) v2(url2);
```

[Here](http://rextester.com/MHSX42288) is a rextester.

Comment: This looks good the character after the number could be a & or / though

Comment: In the sample data, it is always a slash, although it would be easy enough to use `patindex()` instead of `charindex()` for whatever character you choose.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use char index and substring to achieve what you want.. 
here is one way to do it.. not necessarily the best way.. but still.. I've broken it down by steps.. so you can see what is happening.

```
declare @string nvarchar (500) = 'default/default/orig/docid=999980/pageno/1/dw_get'
;with mycte as (
select 
@string as original_string
,   charindex('docid/',@string) [doc/]
,   charindex('docid=',@string) [doc=]
,case when 
        charindex('docid/',@string) <>0 then substring(@string,charindex('docid/',@string),100) 
            else  substring(@string,charindex('docid=',@string),100)  end as stripped
,replace(replace(case when 
        charindex('docid/',@string) <>0 then substring(@string,charindex('docid/',@string),100) 
            else  substring(@string,charindex('docid=',@string),100)  end,'docid/',''),'docid=','') remove_docid
)

Select 
        original_string
        ,[doc/]
        ,[doc=]
        ,stripped
        ,remove_docid
        ,left(remove_docid,CHARINDEX('/',remove_docid)-1) as document_no

 from mycte
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Monah's responses i came up with:

```
select 
    Document_id, 
    EXTERNAL_REF, 
  CASE WHEN 
        substring(substring(EXTERNAL_REF,CHARINDEX('docid',EXTERNAL_REF,0)+6,len(EXTERNAL_REF)),0,CHARINDEX('/',substring(EXTERNAL_REF,CHARINDEX('docid',EXTERNAL_REF,0)+6,len(EXTERNAL_REF)),0)) = '' 
    THEN
    substring(substring(EXTERNAL_REF,CHARINDEX('docid',EXTERNAL_REF,0)+6,len(EXTERNAL_REF)),0,CHARINDEX('&',substring(EXTERNAL_REF,CHARINDEX('docid',EXTERNAL_REF,0)+6,len(EXTERNAL_REF)),0)) 
    ELSE 
    substring(substring(EXTERNAL_REF,CHARINDEX('docid',EXTERNAL_REF,0)+6,len(EXTERNAL_REF)),0,CHARINDEX('/',substring(EXTERNAL_REF,CHARINDEX('docid',EXTERNAL_REF,0)+6,len(EXTERNAL_REF)),0))
  END as DOCID 
    into [new table] 
    from [source Table]
    where EXTERNAL_REF like 'some String'
```

Maybe not the most elegant but works for me.
Thanks all for you prompt suggestions.